# Setting height attribute on div with JQuery yields inconsistent behavior

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple three column (divs) page with a center content column bounded by two sidebars. My sidebars will remain relatively static with the content column being dynamic page-to-page. My goal is to ensure the sidebars retain the same height as the content column and after mashing together something in CSS, I figured a simple JQuery solution would be far cleaner. Enter the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setDivAttributes();
});

function setDivAttributes() {
    $("#sidebar-left").height($("#content").height());
    $("#sidebar-right").height($("#content").height());
}
```

This works perfect, when it runs and therein lies the problem. I can't get this simple bit of code to run reliably. It works fine in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3a2670e/) but when I run it in various browsers, I get inconsistent behavior. Sometimes it will load perfect. Sometimes I need to refresh once, sometimes multiple times and sometimes I have to restart whatever browser altogether. I figured maybe the code was running before the content div had finished loading but every solution I've encountered fails to solve the problem.

I suspect there is a simple solution but it has evaded me so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with a simple flex layout you dont need any javascript at all.
You just wrap content and the sidebars in a flex container and then give it widths.

You will end up with clean css as well

```
.flexLayout {
  display:flex;
  background:black;
}

#content {
  flex:1;
  background:white
}

#sidebar-left,
#sidebar-right {
  width: 180px;
}
```

**DEMO**: https://jsfiddle.net/g3a2670e/1/

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @ilwcss does works.

However, if you want a jQuery solution, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  setDivAttributes();

  $(window).on('resize', setDivAttributes);

  function setDivAttributes(){
    $("#sidebar-left, #sidebar-right").css({
      height: $('#content').height()
    });
  }

});
```

The code you posted used `.height(value)` instead of `.css('height', 'value')`, which might cause the problem you stated according to [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/height/), as quoted below:

> Note that `.height()` will always return the content height, regardless of the value of the CSS `box-sizing` property. As of jQuery 1.8, this may require retrieving the CSS height plus `box-sizing` property and then subtracting any potential border and padding on each element when the element has `box-sizing: border-box`. To avoid this penalty, use `.css( "height" )` rather than `.height()`.

Note that I also added `$(window).on('resize', setDivAttributes);` to ensure the heights of sidebars are the same with content div in case your user resize the browser (i.e., mobile portrait orientation to landscape orientation).